Who? When? What?  (Extra long)
What (3-word phrase) is it called? Let the "invisible" hint guide you.
[•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...  
       [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...  
   [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]... 
           [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...  
                                       [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...  
   [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...
                                     [•][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][0][][][]...               


No knowledge required except for determine the answer.

This one looks really promising +1

The image cuts off on the right...we can see the whole thing by going to an edit window, but maybe it would be useful to just provide the number of $[]'s$ per line?  Unless I am misreading, the $[0]'s$ are always the fourth from the right in each line, so it's just the number of brackets that matters.

@lulu The number of [ ]'s are 50 in every row. Yes, 0's are fourth from the right.

Number of spaces before each line: 4, 11, 7, 15, 43, 7, 41. After: 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 15

@BenjaminWang: 3rd line only has 1 space after it, also you have added 4 extra spaces that are only (maybe?) there because of code-block formatting.

The answer to this is:

 The Year of Confusion - the nickname given to the year 46BC. This is renowned for being the longest year in history, ending up with 445 days due to a recalibration of the calendar system under Julius Caesar. This explains the 'extra long' in the title.

How to find this?

 Note that in the pattern replicated in each row the dot appears in the first 'box' (pair of brackets) and the digit '0' appears 46 boxes later. The ellipsis at the end is supposed to make us realise we are dealing with an ever-ongoing timeline, where each box is a year. The dot therefore indicates the year that comes 46 years "before 0", suggesting 46BC.

 (Of course, '0' was never an actual year - the year 1BC is immediately followed by the year 1AD. We're not supposed to think that it is here, it's just the concept of 'going negative' by 46 years...)

The invisible hint referred to in the puzzle is found if you...

 ...look at the offset for each row. Particularly, if you consider the first row's dot to be an anchor, and map each subsequent row's dot up to where it is relatively positioned along the top row, these will occupy its 3rd, 1st, 5th, 19th, 1st and 18th bracket pairs. If we convert these numbers into letters via A1Z26 they give us C-A-E-S-A-R, i.e. spelling out Caesar. Since there is little fodder text to perform a Caesar shift cipher on (which would be the puzzler's natural first inference here!), this leads us to think instead of the man most commonly associated with the term: Julius Caesar, who was the leader of the Roman Empire in 46BC, giving us a confirmatory hint that we have struck upon the correct concept lying behind this puzzle.

So our "Who? When? What?" in the title is perhaps best answered as references to...

 ...Julius Caesar, in the year 46BC, recalibrating the calendar in the 445-day year that became known as the Year of Confusion.


i liked where you went at first, but i think rot13(pnrfne unf gb qb jvgu gur plcure enugre guna gur zna). we'll see if you're correct, i guess!

@Themoonisacheese That was my initial suspicion too but there just doesn't seem to be any fodder for it anywhere, hence my conclusion it is intended as an association only... Happy to be corrected if anyone else can spot something promising!

You got "3." correct! The 50 is not important however, I could've made a lot more brackets after the 50th bracket (and before the first bracket too btw) hence the dots "...". The only important part is the dot in relation to 0. Try combine  "3." and that part somehow!

@Prim3numbah Ah, you know what, I've just worked it out! There's not much to go on here but the answer is there after all...

Looks good now, nice job!

@Prim3numbah A new Wikipedia rabbithole for me, thanks :)
